# Demora no processamento massivo de ajax CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, desempenho

Meu codigo importa dados de um banco de dados para outro. Para evitar sobrecarga no servidor, estou importando de 100 em 100 registros em cada ajax. Notei que nas primeiras requisições, demora cerca de 40ms, porém, conforme vai mandando mais requisições, o tempo de retorno cresce bastante para 80ms, 100ms até os 400ms.
Estou utilizando a conexão com mysql do framework CodeIgniter; Estou também utilizando, em uma única parte do código, uma conexão mysqli do php, e fechando ela em toda requisição. 
Não estou entendo o motivo de conforme vai aumentando a quantidade de requisições vai demorando mais. Será que a conexão do CodeIgniter não está fechando como esperado?

Comment: Complicado dizer algo, o ideal serial rodar um profile para tentar achar o gargalo e aí tentar resolver o problema. Índices podem tornar instruções como insert ou update mais lentas. Como é feita essa importação, poderia colocar o código?

Comment: A importação monta uma query SELECT baseado em algumas informações que eu passo, até aqui eu só rodei queries de Select e não tem porque aumentar o tempo de retorno. Em seguida em coloco esse Select em um INSERT IGNORE e fecho a conexão. O código é muito grande, não tem como passar por aqui. Não entendo o motivo dos retornos virem cada vez mais demorados se eu faço as mesmas consultas (só alterando o LIMIT do select)

Answer (score 0):

Vinícius, você está usando AJAX para executar essa importação por que ela deve ser acionada/solictada pelo usuário apenas?

Caso seja possível, você pode configurar uma tarefa cron e executar isso automaticamente em um horário específico.

Na tarefa cron você pode ter uma rotina que seria o seguinte:

Faz um select obtendo os dados a serem importados, uma tabela de cada vez, armazena esses dados em variáveis (eles serão um array ou objeto) e então usa o batch process do CodeIgniter.

```
$this->db->insert_batch()
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch